# React Router "Link to" does not load new data when called from inside the same component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

## Background

I am building an app with the following details

- react
- react-router
- redux
- it is universal javascript
- node js

## Problem

When routing with the `Link` tag from component to component it works perfectly. It calls the data that the component requires and renders the page. But when I click on a `Link` that uses the same component as the current one all I see is the url change.

## Attempts

Things I have tried to get this to work.

### Attempt 1

So far I have tried the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846337/how-to-fetch-the-new-data-in-response-to-react-router-change-with-redux) question but the solution wont work for me. This was the code I implemented

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.article.get('id') !== this.props.article.get('id')) {
        console.log('i got trigggerd YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSS');
    }
}
```

But the variable `nextProps` is always the same as the current props.

### Attempt 2

I decided to call the same code I use in `componentWillMount` but that didn't work either.

```
componentWillMount() {
    let { category, slug } = this.props.params;
    this.props.loadArticleState({ category, slug });
}
```

It just creates an infinite loop when I put this into `componentWillReceiveProps`.

## Conclusion

I belief the problem is clicking the link never calls the data associated with it. Since the data is loaded with

```
static fetchData({ store, params }) {
    let { category, slug } = params;
    return store.dispatch(loadArticleState({ category, slug }));
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try force [pushing](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) the new history instead?

Comment: where should this be pushed? in the main Article component or in the `Link to` tag?

Comment: Instead of `<Link>`, it'll be a element (ex. button, span) with `onClick` that triggers `.push(/* whatever was in to= */)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution I Used

I created a function to test if the previous data is the same as the changed data.

```
compareParams(prevProps, props) {
    if (!prevProps || typeof prevProps.params !== typeof props.params) {
        return false;
    }
    return Object.is(props.params, prevProps.params);
}
```

#### So this tests

- are there any previous props?
- and then if the props are equal to the previous props?
- then return false if there are if this is the case
- if not then we see compare props and previous props parameters

#### In ComponentDidUpdate

In the `compoonentDidUpdate` we use this function to determine if the data should be updated

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.compareParams(prevProps, this.props)) {
        return;
    }
    this.props[this.constructor.reducerName](this.props.params);
}
```

## Conclusion

This code updates the body of a page that uses the same react component if it receives new data.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try use onChange event on Route component, check [Route API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route) and then signal to child component that refresh is needed...