# React Router master-detail: children component don't render new view until page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, nested-routes, react-router-component

I am creating a master-detail navigation just like the example here [the react router example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/master-detail/app.js);

I have a container component `OneCheckpointContainer`, which renders a navigation panel `CheckpointNav` (the links), and a data component `OneCheckpointData` (this guy fetchs data upon load, and renders `OneCheckpointView`.

When I click one of the links in `CheckpointNav` nothing happens except the URL in the browser changes. It is not until I refresh the page that new data is fetched, and a new component is then rendered in the children view. (there are also no errors)

I am not sure if this bug is because the child component is also responsible for fetching data, as well as the view.

**Here is how I have the routes setup:**

```
  <Route path="/modules/:id" component={OneCheckpointContainer}>
    <Route path="/modules/:id/checkpoints/:cp_id" component={OneCheckpointData} />
  </Route>
```

**OneCheckpointContainer**

```
import React from 'react';
import CheckpointNav from './CheckpointNav';

class OneCheckpointContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      checkpoints: null,
      user: null
    };

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadCheckpoints();
    this.context.getUser((data) => this.setState({ user: data }));
  }

  loadCheckpoints() {
    $.ajax({
      url: `/api/v1/modules/student/${this.props.params.id}/checkpoints`,
      method: 'GET',
    }).done((data) => {
      this.setState({ checkpoints: data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-xs-3">
          <CheckpointNav mid={this.props.params.id} checkpoints={this.state.checkpoints} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-9">
          { this.props.children || <div>No Children Yet</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

OneCheckpointContainer.displayName = OneCheckpointContainer;

OneCheckpointContainer.contextTypes = {
  getUser: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default OneCheckpointContainer;
```

Here is **CheckpointNav** though I don't believe the bug is in here:

```
import React from 'react';
import NavLink from '../widgets/NavLink';

const CheckpointNav = (props) => {
  const checkpointList = props.checkpoints && props.checkpoints.length > 0 ?
    props.checkpoints.map((item) => {
      return <li key={item.cp._id} className="list-group-item">
      <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/modules/" + props.mid + "/checkpoints/" + item.cp._id}>
      { item.cp.title}</NavLink></li>
    }) : <div>No CPS</div>;
  return (
    <div className="card one-module-card">
      <div className="card-block modules-card-body">
        <ul className="list-group tags-group">
          { checkpointList }
          <li className="list-group-item new-cp"><NavLink className=""
            to={'/post/checkpoint/' + props.mid}
          >
            New Checkpoint
          </NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

};

export default CheckpointNav;
```

**OneCheckpointData**
*doesn't fetch new data and render new unless I refresh*

```
import React from 'react';
import CheckpointView from './CheckpointView';

class OneCheckpointData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      checkpoint: null,
      user: null
    };

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadCheckpoint();
    this.context.getUser((data) => this.setState({ user: data }));
  }

  loadCheckpoint() {
    $.ajax({
      url: `/api/v1/modules/three/cp/${this.props.params.cp_id}`,
      method: 'GET',
    }).done((data) => {
      this.setState({ checkpoint: data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.checkpoint ? <CheckpointView user={this.state.user} checkpoint={this.state.checkpoint} /> : null;
  }
}

OneCheckpointData.displayName = OneCheckpointData;

OneCheckpointData.contextTypes = {
  getUser: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default OneCheckpointData;
```

** I have left out OneCheckpointView  since it should be irrelavant **

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In, that case you can get the props as the parameter of `loadCheckpoing(props)` function and you can send the new props on the `componentWillReceiveProps` just like below

```
componentWillMount(this.props) {
  this.loadCheckpoint(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
  this.loadCheckpoint(nextprops);
}

loadCheckpoint(props) {
  this.context.getUser((data) => this.setState({ user: data }));
  $.ajax({
    url: `/api/v1/modules/three/cp/${props.params.cp_id}`, //please check i have replace the this.props to props as we have props as a parameter
    method: 'GET',
  }).done((data) => {
    this.setState({ checkpoint: data });
  });
}
```

i will prefer to use react-redux or reflux library to handle your ajax data query but my proposed solution should do the job for you.

Comment: I think I understand what you are going for, but you can not pass this.props in as an arg to componentWillMount

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your components are fetching data only before mounting. This only works for the first time they are displayed. These components also need to fetch their data whenever they receive new properties, e.g. ids from the router after navigating to a new location.

In order to do so, the simplest way is to add a `componentWillReceiveProps` that compares the previous props with the new one and fetches the new data if required.

An alternative way is to add an `onEnter` handler in your Routes configuration to fetch the data whenever a route is changed.

Check [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846337/how-to-fetch-the-new-data-in-response-to-react-router-change-with-redux) to see examples of both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you have invoked the function loadcheckpoints in componentwillMount. This is be invoked only once in the component lifecycle.
Since the component is already mounted when you had clicked a link in the nav bar, the compoenntwillmount will not be invoked.Hence, no fetch of data occurs.

I guess, you should try the following approach.
The onclick function of the links in CheckpointNav should be passed from OneCheckpointContainer . The loadeddata should be set to state in the container which will pass on the data to OneCheckpointData as props .

Answer (score 1):

Two steps to diagnosis:

1. check whether your method `loadCheckpoint` has been called every time when you click different link. Just leave one line like `console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())` in that method
2. if step 1 success, then check whether there is a `this` reference issue in this part:

   `(data) => {
       this.setState({ checkpoint: data });
   }`

BTW, you'd better put the ajax call in `componentDidMount` method. Refer to: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount